# Liquibase liquibase-maven-plugin creates tables but tables cannot be found in Integration Tests: org.hibernate.HibernateException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, liquibase

I am using Liquibase. I want the database tables to be created before the Integration Tests.

The code is located on GitHib: https://github.com/rajivj2/example2/

The EmployeeJpaDAOIT.java is the class that contains the test. All I want to do is have the tables created before the test actually starts. I can see the plugin creates the tables at runtime but the Integration Tests throws the following Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: employee
```

Can you please help?

Comment: I have updated the code to include the integration test phase.

Answer (score 0):

```
<phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
 <goals>
  <goal>update</goal>
 </goals>
</phase>
```

Why you have goal:update?

Comment: Because this one is one the website http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_update.html. The one looks suitable for creating the tables.